# How to handle two JSON response with Retrofit and RxJa?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am sending API request to the server and I can get two JSON response:

- JSON response for authenticated user
- JSON response for unauthenticated user

Authenticated user response:

```
{"status":"ok","tekst":"8bc6c9cf-293f-11e5-9940-448a5b5dd2bd","requestID":9034}
```

Unauthenticated user response:

```
{"authenticationError":"User authentication failed"}
```

Retrofit service:

```
public interface LiveService {
    @GET("live.php")
    Observable<Response<LiveResponse>> getLive();
}
```

This is Retrofit request to the server:

```
retrofit.create(LiveService.class)
            .getLive()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<LiveResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    liveView.onLiveError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<LiveResponse> response) {


                }
            });
```

**How I can handle response in onNext to check if I am geting JSON response for authenticated user or for unauthenticated user?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with StarWind, adding another field will help you later decide how to handle the response, but first you need to tweak your method where the end result is not `Response<T>` but rather the body (object). This could be done easily with `RxJava` by chaining calls in following manner: Receive the response, check if it is successfull, check if the deserialized body object contains authentication error field.

```
retrofit.create(LiveService.class).getLive().flatMap(new Function<Response<LiveResponse>, ObservableSource<LiveResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<LiveResponse> apply(Response<LiveResponse> liveResponse) throws Exception {
                LiveResponse body =  liveResponse.body();
                if(liveResponse.isSuccessful() && body != null && body.getAuthenticationError() == null){ //probably check http error code too
                    return Observable.just(body);
                }else if(body != null){
                    throw new AuthenticationException(body.getAuthenticationError());
                }else{
                 throw IllegalArgumentException("something terribly happened here"); }
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<LiveResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    liveView.onLiveError(e); //authentication error maybe or network excp
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(LiveResponse body) {


                }
            });
```

Note that I used `RxJava 2`, but you can easily rewrite it in RxJava 1.

Answer (score 5):

Your model will need to have all the fields for both combined into one POJO. That simple :-)

The ones for the authenticated user / unauthenticated user that were not present will just be null.

To be more clear...

Lets take two different replies. Here are two random JSON payloads I came across.

```
   {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    }



   { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    }
```

Leads us to a combined object like

```
    {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500,
    "src": "ImagesSun.png",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 250,
    "alignment": "center"
   }
```

giving us a POJO that looks like this.

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private String alignment;

    private String title;

    private String hOffset;

    private String height;

    private String width;

    private String name;

    private String src;

    private String vOffset;

    public String getAlignment ()
    {
        return alignment;
    }

    public void setAlignment (String alignment)
    {
        this.alignment = alignment;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getHOffset ()
    {
        return hOffset;
    }

    public void setHOffset (String hOffset)
    {
        this.hOffset = hOffset;
    }

    public String getHeight ()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight (String height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getWidth ()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth (String width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSrc ()
    {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc (String src)
    {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public String getVOffset ()
    {
        return vOffset;
    }

    public void setVOffset (String vOffset)
    {
        this.vOffset = vOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [alignment = "+alignment+", title = "+title+", hOffset = "+hOffset+", height = "+height+", width = "+width+", name = "+name+", src = "+src+", vOffset = "+vOffset+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This one should be marked as correct and very simple answer! BTW, StarWind0, if have only 1 different value and it's int, how u check it for null?

Comment: Make it a string and check for null, then convert it to an int, you might can use capital Integer classes. Though its been a while.

Answer (score 2):

The retrofit can handle only one data type. Maybe you can create the main user object with authenticated_user & unauthenticated_user objects. Maybe you should ask the backend team to return a boolean or any variable to identify the type of data.

```
class User {
AuthUser authUser;
UnAuthUser unAuthUSer;
}
```